# Is there any API for raw sockets in Java also example would be helpful

Tags: java, sockets

I want to create a simple http asyn client interface that sends the get request and recieve the response from the server.

Though I want to control the number of request sends per second also the response is a asyn handling.

The key is I want to specify number of request per second so as to load the server.

I have searched that Ning AsyncHttpClient interface but it does allow to set the number of requests per second. So I think to use RAW sockets in Java and create interface like it.

Can you please help me in suggesting what framework provide these functionality or else what API I use to achieve this functionlaity.

Thanks,
Manish

Comment: Just create a simple class that sends and receives a request, then get the time before the request was sent, then again after. Get the difference then wait until that delta time is up and repeat. Pretty simple

Comment: I would control the request rate yourself.  You can have a loop which sends requests and sleeps until the next request should be sent.

Comment: Why would you want to use raw sockets for http, you'd need to implement TCP yourself

Comment: You should not use RAW sockets for this but rather search the java.net package. Especially java.net.URLConnection and java.net.HttpURLConnection. Here is a nice answer that might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests

Answer (score 2):

No, Java doesn't support raw sockets, although  various third party libraries do. I don't see anything in your question that needs them.